# Using if statement to prevent "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java

I'm using a method that returns a list that is fetched from a web service. This list sometimes does not contain anything. Which results in "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"

```
  ArrayList<String> placesList = osm.getPlace(poi, listingCity, listingState);
  if (placesList != null) 
  { 
    poi = placesList.get(0);
    poiStreet = placesList.get(1); 
  }
```

I have used the if statement above to prevent the exception, but it does not work. Is there anyway I can prevent this Exception by using if statements so the program do something else in case the list is empty?

Comment: you are assuming that the array has >=2 or no elements, what if it has only 1 element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure the list is not null, and, contains at least two elements, do this:

```
if( placesList != null && placesList.size() >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list could be defined, but have no strings in it (an empty list).  You should also check the size of the list:

```
ArrayList<String> placesList = osm.getPlace(poi, listingCity, listingState);
if (placesList != null && placesList.size() > 1) 
{ 
  poi = placesList.get(0);
  poiStreet = placesList.get(1); 
}
```

Comment: it should be `>1` as op is also getting the second element

Answer (score 0):

The list object is not null, but the contents inside can be zero

Use placeList.size() to check the number of contents inside.

Answer (score 0):

If `ArrayList == null` returns `true` it doesn't mean that it's empty, it means that it hasn't been initialized and it points to `null`.

In order to check if your list is empty, you can use

```
if (!placesList.isEmpty()){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because the ArrayList object is not null, does not imply there are any elements in it.

You can call isEmpty() or size() methods to determine if there are any elements in the array.

Try this:

```
  ArrayList<String> placesList = osm.getPlace(poi, listingCity, listingState);
  if (placesList != null && placesList.isEmpty() == false ) 
  { 
    poi = placesList.get(0);
    poiStreet = placesList.get(1); 
  }
```

[Javadoc reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the ArrayList is not null, then add a second condition ensuring the size is equal to 2 to ensure it contains what you expect

```
if (placesList != null && placesList.size() == 2)
```

Comment: What if its greater than 2?

Comment: In this particular case he's expecting 2 items. If The ArrayList can contain more and that's not an error condition then he can obviously update it to be whatever he likes. I feel being precise with what you're expecting is the correct answer here, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if (placeList.size() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check length of the arraylist.
something like

```
if (placesList.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is by:

```
 if(placesList.isEmpty())
 {
   //do something here when empty
 }
 else
 {
   poi = placesList.get(0);
 }
```